# "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'." error in android studio

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-4.1

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3g0n.png)

I am getting this error just today.

Android studio is saying `com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.` can't be downloaded.

Here is my gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

This only occurs if I download a project from the web. If I create the project then everything works fine.

Should I download `com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.` myself or is anything missing in my gradle file?

Comment: remove last dot in com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.

Answer (score 0):

// build.gradle (Project: YOUR-APP)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

// build.gradle (Module: App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}   

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: It isn't working. I put `implementation 'com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1'` in my gradle but still I get `Could not find com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.` as error in build logs. Yes I have removed the last dot. I even tried to put `implementation com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.` but also I get the same error

Comment: Here is my repo with only build.gradle: https://github.com/Aditya425/parse-project