# "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0." error in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvEQH.png)

I started getting this error after I imported an project downloaded from the web.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I added the above files after seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65262483/could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-classpath-error-in-android-s)

But still I am getting an error.

I tried `Inavalidate caches/restart`, `clean and rebuild project`, `sync gradle`.

For some reason `Add google Maven repository and sync project` doesn't work at all. If I click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete the `.` in the end of

```
  implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.'
```

to make it

```
  implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

and try if it is still the same